# How can I print value out of if condition when I get value from isset post?

Tags: php, if-statement, post, isset

I'm trying to echo the variable value out of if and `isset` area.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $today_date = date("Y-m-d");
  $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
  $fullName_user = $_POST['fullName_user'];
}
echo $today_date;
```

How can I print out of if condition?

Comment: Put your `echo` inside the if statement.. not sure what you're asking

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please add more details.

Comment: Something like this? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/901e02c5ef97d32ed881d24a3e715cf938991dc7

Comment: Please remember to flag/vote when a question is **Unclear**.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, variable *$today_date* isn't initialized outside of the if statement.

You should give it default value before the if statement if you want to use it outside.

Also, it make sense for this variable to be outside of the if statement, because it doesn't depend on submit, it just represents today's date.

```
$today_date = date("Y-m-d");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
    $fullName_user = $_POST['fullName_user'];
}

echo $today_date;
```